# SSH proxy error

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd

I would like to be able to establish an SSH connection to a remote server, through an IPSec tunnel. So I need to use the local endpoint as an intermediate hop to achieve this.

The following command already works fine:

`ssh -tt smals ssh -tt lpextapp050a`

- `smals` is the name of the intermediate server, as defined in my `.ssh/config` file.
- `lpextapp050a` is the name of the destination server, as defined in the `.ssh/config` file of `smals`

So I tried translating this into a configuration for my `.ssh/config` as follows:

```
Host lpextapp050a
User <username>
ProxyCommand ssh root@smals -W lpextapp050a:22
```

However, attempting to connect with `ssh lpextapp050a` gives me this error:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Google seemed to indicate I needed to check the `AllowTcpForwarding` and `PermitOpen` settings of the sshd on `smals`, but those are correctly set,  ie. they are not present in the settings file. I tried specifically setting them, which did not change anything.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm a bit ambivalent about the 'possible duplicate'... That question has no accepted answer and I tried the nr. 1 answer without success. It turns out that the nr. 2 answer was sort of relevant, but is not explained clearly enough for me to realize this before I found the solution myself... Answer nr. 7 did end up pointing me to the right logfile to read.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered my error.

The `lpextapp050a` alias was defined in the `.ssh/config` file of the `root` user of the `smals` server.

When making the connection using `ssh -tt smals ssh -tt lpextapp050a` this config file was loaded and honored.

Trying to establish the same using the ProxyCommand did **not** load this config file. I finally managed to discover this by reading the `/var/log/auth.log` file on my `smals` server.

Thus, I solved my problem by basically copying over the relevant parts (IP, user) into my local configuration file.